# Using Uri strings that may or may not have trailing /'s

Tags: c#, uri, dotnet-httpclient

I've been using the HttpClient in code for a while now and have always felt its use of `Uris` has resulted in some brittleness in my implementation.  Most of our service endpoint base addresses are in the app./web.config.  As a result, they can be easily changed.

I've found that when using these endpoint strings to generate a `Uri`, if they don't end in a `/`, I get really wonky behavior.  When calling `GetAsync()` with a non-`/`-terminated `BaseAddress`, the resulting concatenated URL that is sent the GET request often drops either the string after the final `/` in the `BaseAddress`, or it will drop the string preceeding the first `/` in the GetUri.

For example:

`BaseAddress`: `http://test/serviceEndpoint`

`GetUri`: `api/customer`

When `HttpClient.GetAsync()` is called with that `GetUri`, it will attempt to GET from `http://test/api/customer`.  If I cap `BaseAddress` with a `/`, everything works as expected.

**My problem** is that `BaseAddress` is config-driven, and putting in a comment in the .config file saying "Make sure you end all Service URLs with a `/`!" is a really brittle solution.

So I've gotten into the habit of using the following code in all of my `HttpClient` construction:

```
        var service = settings.GetValue("ServiceBaseUrl");
        var serviceUri = !service.EndsWith("/")
            ? new Uri(service + "/")
            : new Uri(service);

        _client = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = serviceUri
        };`
```

While this isn't brittle, it feels repetitive to have it in every `HttpClient` constructor.  Is there something in either `HttpClient` or `Uri` that I can use to avoid this boilerplate code?

Comment: You can try to wrap the logic in an extension method to reduce the amount of repetition.  And you would use var serviceUri = service.GetBaseURL() through out your app. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: Just an edge case thought: `serviceUri = service.TrimEnd('/') + "/"` would catch situations where the `ServiceBaseUrl` ends with more than one `/` and situations where it doesn't end with a `/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing in HttpClient or Uri to address this, which is why I addressed it in a couple ways in [Flurl](https://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/). Flurl's `AppendPathSegment` and `AppendPathSegments` methods will ensure one and only one "/" separator between segments. For example, these yield the identical results:

```
"http://mysite/".AppendPathSegment("/endpoint")
"http://mysite".AppendPathSegment("endpoint")
```

The static `Url.Combine` method also has this behavior, acting as sort of a `Path.Combine` for URLs.

These and other helpful URL-building bits are available in the core [Flurl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl/) package, but the real fun is in [Flurl.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl.Http/), which combines the fluent URL builder with a lightweight wrapper on top of HttpClient and Json.NET that lets you go from string to URL to HTTP request to deserialized result without lifting pen from paper, so to speak:

```
var result = await settings.GetValue("ServiceBaseUrl")
    .AppendPathSegment("endpoint")
    .GetJsonAsync<T>();
```